# Why Object.create polyfill using prototype of Function instead of simple __proto__ of Object?

Tags: javascript

I read the [Object.create() polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) on the MDN. They create a new Function and set its `prototype` property to the passing object as following:

```
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
  Object.create = (function() {
    var Temp = function() {};
    return function (prototype) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) {
        throw Error('Second argument not supported');
      }
      if (typeof prototype != 'object') {
        throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');
      }
      Temp.prototype = prototype;
      var result = new Temp();
      Temp.prototype = null;
      return result;
    };
  })();
}
```

I'm very curious that why it didn't be simply just using `__proto__` as following:

```
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
  Object.create = (function() {
    var temp = {};
    return function (prototype) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) {
        throw Error('Second argument not supported');
      }
      if (typeof prototype != 'object') {
        throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');
      }
      temp.__proto__ = prototype;
      return temp;
    };
  })();
}
```

I have tried to run both of these solutions and the result is the same:

[image]

In my opinion, the `__proto__` is shorter and easier to read. Do I miss somethings important behind the scene of the standard solution?

Comment: Actually, the implementation with `__proto__` is not fully equivalent to the MDN polyfill. Look at my comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647143/why-object-create-polyfill-using-prototype-of-function-instead-of-simple-proto#34648620.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `__proto__` is not a standard property until ECMAScript 6. So, one cannot use it without risking.

Also, there is the main idea behind using `new` keyword in JavaScript - creating new objects with the specified prototype. And you can create objects with `new` only through a constructor function. So, MDNs implementation of `Object.create()` polyfill is pretty idiomatic.

That is, the final answer is: until `Object.create()` was [invented](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) by Douglas Crockford there was only one way to create objects with the specified prototype. And this way was using `new MyCtr()`, where `MyCtr.prototype` was equal to the desired one. Furthermore, this way was a native way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Gotta make it more detailed than that.

Comment: __proto__ is a standard property in ES6. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.__proto__